# How could I return 4 random rows in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, random

This is my calling code from PHP currently:

```
$getfromdb = "SELECT `myTable`.* FROM `myTable` WHERE `status`=1 and ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4";
```

This is sufficient enough for now, as the number of rows in the table is pretty small (<1000). 
However,

(a) the randomness is not enough (meaning some of the same rows are being returned pretty often), and

(b) the size of the table will increase very quickly, meaning performance will take a hit.

How could I make this such that the code could be more random and efficient?

There is an autoincrement on the primary key (id) - but there are holes as well.

Comment: You could create random numbers in PHP and select where ID equals that random number.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the table's approximated cardinality, I think you can set `OFFSET`randomly. For example:

```
$cardinality = 100000;
$limit = 4;
$offset = rand(0, $cardinality - $limit);
$getfromdb = "
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT `myTable`.* FROM `myTable` WHERE `status` = 1
        OFFSET $offset LIMIT 500
    ) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $limit
";
```

Well, its sampling method has bias however.

Comment: Maybe you meant `ORDER BY rand()` in the end instead of `ORDER BY $limit`